# Twitter Bootstrap Select Combo Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm am using a combo box to display a number of items by using the following code

```
    <select  class="form-control input-lg">
        @{

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++ )
            {
                <text><option style="height:2em; padding-top:5px; font-size:inherit">@i</option></text>
            }    
        }
    </select>
```

The select displays a very tall dropdown list before activating the scroll bar. The scroll bar displays after the content is bigger than 20 rows.

I would to make the it's size to be smaller, let's say the scroll bar should appear if the content is bigger than 7 rows.

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [Bootstrap-Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin. This plugins has the option `data-size` which is used to determine the size of the dropdown/scrollbar container. It also has many more cool features, but it's not vanilla bootstrap, so if you don't want to use other libraries than bootstrap this answer is not suitable :) .

Comment: Thanks! This might be a solution. I am also using KendoUI libraries for certain components and I would not prefer to include any other libraries. But unless I find another solution, I'm going to give this a try.